# Straighten vertical wood in gate

Tags: wood, outdoor

I have a 4 leaf wooden gate. The leaf that is used as a pedestrian access has a bolt at the top and nothing at the bottom.  This means that as the sun has dried the wood it has bowed toward the sunlight.
The gate is made from pressure treated redwood, and has been painted with a polyurethane lacquer.

I have tried to re-hang the leaf but cannot straighten it such that there is no gap at the bottom.  I can, through applying a bit of manual pressure straighten the wood.

I thought that adding 40mmx40mm angle iron the length of the edge of the leaf would help bring it back into line and should prevent it from warping again.

Is this a suitable fix for a driveway gate?
Are there any foreseeable issues with my plan?
Are there alternatives?

[image: bowed gate leaf]
[image: example of fix - shown using aluminium angle instead of steel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a metal angle or channel. I'd probably go with aluminum over steel for corrosion resistance and weight savings. Something like 2x2x1/4" should do. The advantage of this approach is that you can paint it to camouflage it. You many need to shorten the door to allow space.

However, a lighter solution is **a turnbuckle with a spacer**. Attach the turnbuckle vertically at top and bottom to the convex side of the gate (ideally with through-bolts for strength), and stand a block at the middle (or *two* if one would interfere with the turnbuckle nut). These could be simply wood scraps screwed in place, say 2" tall, but you can also find metal rod standoffs. Frankly I'd trust the block more. Snug it up and watch the gate straighten out.

If you find difficulty, try a taller block. Over time, as the door straightens, this can be reduced. Or work the curve out in stages, giving the wood time to relax. I could also help to moisten the concave side.